# Measure assortativity of vertices using igraph r

Tags: r, igraph

I need to measure the assortativity of vertices, not of the entire graph. How do I do this?

Take the following graph:

```
g <- sample_gnm(n=20,m=20)
plot(g)
V(g)$gender <- c("male","female")
V(g)$gender[1:10] <- "male"
V(g)$gender[11:20] <- "female"
assortativity.nominal(g,types=V(g)$gender)
```

Now we have the assortativity of graph g. How to measure the assortativity of the vertices of g, or a similar measure at the vertex level?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have a reference or a name for it, but what about the following measure?

```
A <- as.matrix(get.adjacency(g))
(assort <- rowSums(outer(V(g)$gender, V(g)$gender, `==`) * A) / rowSums(A))

#  [1] 0.6000000 0.0000000 0.5000000 0.5000000 0.0000000 0.5000000       NaN 1.0000000
#  [9] 0.2500000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.6666667       NaN       NaN       NaN 0.4000000
# [17] 0.0000000 0.0000000 1.0000000 0.3333333
```

For each vertex it provides a proportion of its neighbours that are of the same type as the given vertex. The coefficients then always fall between 0 and 1 and have a nice interpretation.

In case a vertex doesn't have any neighbours, we have `NaN`; if you wish it to be a zero, then add

```
assort[is.nan(assort)] <- 0
```

Comment: Hi Julius, this seems like an elegant solution. One doubt remains after reading this [blog](http://dappls.umasscreate.net/networks/calculating-network-homophily-part-2/). The author built a function to calculate the proportion of neighbors which share the same label as ego -- your same measure. I tried the blog's solution and your solution on the same graph, and the results are different. You know what the problem may be? Below is the graph I used to compare.

g2 <- make_tree(40,children = 3,mode="undirected")

V(g2)$gender[1:20] <- "male"

V(g2)$gender[21:40] <- "female"

Comment: @NBK, I took a look at the coefficient for the last vertex (0 in my case, and 0.5 in your reference). It is a female having only one neighbour, male. So, it would seem that my approach is fine. After looking at the blog post I see a problem; somehow `ego` additionally returns the vertex itself as its neighbour. It can also be suspected from the fact that the assortativity is never zero with that method.

Comment: Fantastic, I buy it.

Comment: This is clever. I'm trying to do something similar, but my graph is directed. So I'd like to compute node-level assortativity of each node's out-going edges, incoming edges, and all edges. Is there a simple tweak? If not I'll ask a new question.

Comment: @J.Q, you can use `rowSums` (as in the answer), `colSums`, and their sum.